# C# Aforge.net Showing camera feed while other app uses the same camera

Tags: c#, aforge

My first question ever on SO, apologies if something is missing or wrong.

I currently have a WPF app that hooks onto a camera using Aforge.net and shows the feed.
However this does not seem to work when another application is using the camera.

This is how I setup the feed.

```
device.NewFrame += onNewFrame;
device.Start();
```

When I launch the app and another app is using the camera the OnNewFrame method does not get called.
It works normally when nothing else is using the camera.

I tried googling and I found nothing regarding the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because a WIRED camera driver may be used by only one consumer application at a time.

Alternatively use IP Camera's where feed is available on a URL.

Comment: Yeah...for some reason I thought two processes can use the same camera. Now I feel dumb, thanks though.

Comment: @hoodah - there are applications/sudo drivers that will sit between Camera (driver) and your application(s) and they do video signal multiplication (duplication). Imagine like one app that takes over the camera video feed is publishing the same feed to multiple consumers who connect to it. But is it worth the pain..! thats a question for user may be.